# Unable to install ionic2 on Mac OS by installing node and npm also

Tags: ionic2, npm-install

[image]
**unable to install ionic 2**

Successfully Installed ionic2@beta using

`sudo npm install -g ionic@beta`

`ionic -v` shows version 1.7.14

Uninstalled using `npm uninstall -g ionic`

Successfully (based on printout) uninstalled ionic 2
`ionic -v` shows version 1.7.14 (WTF)

Tried `npm uninstall -g ionic` again

Received command prompt immediately, no other outputs (no affect)
`ionic -v shows version 1.7.14`

Comment: What is your problem? In the error message it says you should run as root/admin, did you try this?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 choices.

As comment suggests do:

```
sudo npm install -g ionic@beta
```

You will have to do this for every global command as you dont have permission to the folders.

Or

Check [npm fix permission issue](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions)

You can change the global node module directory of npm so that you wont need permission. You can also use app like `homebrew` to set up your node.